# STUFF Function Limitations with Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using dynamic SQL to concatenate a bunch of scripts that I have loaded into a table.  It will take those individual scripts, concatenate them into one script, and then put that finished script into another table.  It has worked beautifully so far, concatenating about 17 scripts successfully.  But yesterday, I tried 80.  And there is the issue.  It is capping out at 78,165 characters every time I try it.  The guts of it go like this:

```
 SET @FinScriptSQL
        = N'SELECT script, row_number( ) over( order by scriptTypeId ) as execOrder INTO #' + @FinScriptName
          + N' from dbo.' + @FinScriptName
          + N';
          DECLARE @tsqlStmt NVARCHAR(MAX);
               SELECT @tsqlStmt = STUFF(
               (
                   SELECT (CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + script) AS [text()]
                   FROM #'          + @FinScriptName
                             + N'
                   ORDER BY execOrder
                   FOR XML PATH(''''), TYPE).value(''.'', ''nvarchar( max )''),
                   1   ,
                   1   ,
                   NULL
               );
               
               CREATE TABLE dbo.' + @FinScriptName + N'_FinishedScripts 
                      (
                        Name sysname NULL, 
                        FinishedScript NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL
                      );
               INSERT INTO dbo.' + @FinScriptName + N'_FinishedScripts
                     SELECT ''' + @FinScriptName + N''', @tsqlStmt;'
    PRINT @FinScriptSQL;
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @FinScriptSQL;
```

The column of the table where the individual scripts are is an NVARCHAR(MAX), as is the destination column of the new table.  I thought it might be a setting in SQL Server, so I have already ensured that the maximum characters retrieved is wide open.  Any ideas?

Comment: My first thought... In SSMS options, Query Results > SQL Server > Results to Grid what is your setting for Maximum Characters Retrieved for XML Data?  Set it to Unlimited?  I see you are printing to screen thought.

Comment: Non XML data: 65535 (max setting), XML data - unlimited

Comment: What sql server version are you using? Instead of using `stuff` to concatenate you could use `string_agg` starting with sql server 2017

Comment: I'm using 2016 SP2-CU13.....I remember looking at STRING_AGG.  Sigh.  Things to look forward to!

Comment: For sure this is not bound to `STUFF()` as your question's title suggests. You use this function only to take away the leading line break (hint: have a close look at this. You take away 1 character, while the linebreak has two...). How is `@FinScriptSQL` declared? Check with `LEN()` the actual length and with `RIGHT(@FinScriptSQL,50)` what's acutally the content at the end. Pretty sure this is just truncated in your output. is the execution correct, without the `PRINT`?

Comment: Execution is correct.  The table insert is truncated.at 78,165 characters.  I even tried running this against different drivers (odbc, oledb, sqlnativeclient) to see if that was affecting it.  I'm reaching here, I know.  I'm just running out of ideas.